# Loop through array to give all datas in CSV

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

So I have this code:

```
$list = $this->user_model->get_users($prefKey, $searchKey, $withEmail, "", "");

$headerArray = array("id", "prefecture_id", "industry");

$header = str_replace(",", "", $headerArray);

$datas = implode(',', $header) . "\r\n";

foreach($list as $body)
{
    $orig_email = $body['email'];

    $mstring = preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/",',',$orig_email);

    preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $mstring, $matches);

    $email = implode($matches[0]);

    $datas .= $body["id"].",".$body["prefecture_id"].",".$body["industry_id"].",".$email."\r\n";

    $datas = '"' . implode('","', $body).'"';

}

$datas = mb_convert_encoding($datas, "SJIS-win", "UTF-8");

$csvFileName = "phpList_" . date('Ymd_His') . ".csv";


header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $csvFileName);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
while (ob_get_level() > 0)
{
    ob_end_clean();
}

ob_start();
print trim($datas);
ob_flush();
ob_end_clean();
exit;
```

It only gives like this:

```
"3","Tesla","Cars","admin@volvo.com"
```

What I want is like this:

```
"1","Volvo","Cars","admin@volvo.com"
"2","Honda","Cars","admin@honda.com"
"3","Tesla","Cars","admin@tesla.com"
```

When I call this function it gives csv download file with only 1 data(final data). How can I loop through all of the data?

Comment: For email validation look at [`filter_var()` with the FILTER_VALID_EMAIL constant](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php).

Comment: php also has a function called [`fputcsv` that writes an array of fields to a file.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying that you only get the last record loaded in your csv?

With this line you replace all the data currently in `$datas`:

```
$datas = '"' . implode('","', $body).'"';
```

This way only the last line of the last iteration of your loop ends up being useful for the end result. Not sure if it's the problem, but maybe

```
$datas .= '"' . implode('","', $body).'"';
```

P.s. I am not sure if you want to keep the first line of your `foreach`

P.p.s. You might want to add some line endings to your csv.

Comment: for instance I have changes in the query, like for example column email, I have to validate first the email column because there are unwanted characters/strings, then I put it in $email variable. I edit the codes above. I know this is off-topic to the question, but I really need a helping hand. How can I use the implode function?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is being overwritten

```
foreach($list as $body){
  ....
    $datas .= $body["id"].",".$body["prefecture_id"].",".$body["industry_id"].",".$email."\r\n";

    $datas = '"' . implode('","', $body).'"';  //overwritten by body
}
```

These two lines make little sense the way they are.  Each iteration you += concatenate `$datas`, then you immediately overwrite it with some other data.

For example on the first iteration it is

```
$datas = implode(',', $header) . "\r\n";
$datas .= $body["id"].",".$body["prefecture_id"].",".$body["industry_id"].",".$email."\r\n";
$datas = '"' . implode('","', $body).'"'; //over written
```

The next iteration it is the previous ( last line from above )

```
$datas = '"' . implode('","', $body).'"';
```

Then

```
  $datas .= $body["id"].",".$body["prefecture_id"].",".$body["industry_id"].",".$email."\r\n";
  $datas = '"' . implode('","', $body).'"';  //over written
```

See what I mean it makes no sense.

The only way to make this make sense is to do something like this

```
$datas = [implode(',', $header)];

foreach($list as $body)
{
    $orig_email = $body['email'];

    $mstring = preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/",',',$orig_email);
    preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $mstring, $matches);

    $email = implode($matches[0]);

    $datas[] = [
         $body["id"],
         $body["prefecture_id"],
         $body["industry_id"],
         $email
    ];

}

$datas = imploade(PHP_EOL, $datas);
```

But even that is not really the right way to make a csv file, you should be using `fputcsv`.  What happens if there is a `"` in `$body` your CSV would be junked.

**UPDATE and Solution**

This is how I would code it, but I don't know why you are changing the encoding:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $csvFileName);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

//open the output stream, this acts like a file but just outputs the contents.
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($f, $header);

//create a mapping array for the headers ( if the order is different then $body )
$default = array_fill_keys( $headers, '');
/*
 assuming headers is like this
     ['id', 'prefecture_id', 'industry_id', 'email']
 this will create a "mapping" array like this
     ['id'=>'', 'prefecture_id'=>'', 'industry_id'=>'', 'email'=>'']
*/

foreach($list as $body)
{
    $orig_email = $body['email'];

    $mstring = preg_replace("/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/",',',$orig_email);

    if( preg_match_all("/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i", $mstring, $matches)){  
         $body['email'] = implode($matches[0]);
    }else{
         //prevent undefined offset warning in $matches when there are none.
         $body['email'] = '';
    }

    /*
       merge $body with the mapping array
       if the keys match the '' in $default will be replaced by the 
       value in $body for the same key.
     ----------------------------------------
       assuming data like this '$body'
      ['email' => 'mail@example.com', 'industry_id'=>321,'id'=>1, 'prefecture_id' => 123]
       and our mapping like this '$default'
      ['id'=>'', 'prefecture_id'=>'', 'industry_id'=>'', 'email'=>'']
      this will change $body to
      ['id'=>1, 'prefecture_id'=>123, 'industry_id'=>321, 'email'=>'mail@example.com']
    */
    $body = array_replace($default, $body);

    //after mapping it $body will match $header order and lenght
    //so we just send it to the output stream buffer.
    fputcsv($f, $body);

    //flush the output buffer to the browser.
    flush();
}
```

For reference ( on how to map data to headers )

> array_fill_keys() Fills an array with the value of the value parameter, using the values of the keys array as keys.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

> array_replace() replaces the values of array1 with values having the same keys in each of the following arrays. If a key from the first array exists in the second array, its value will be replaced by the value from the second array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php